# Quickblox android push notifications not working

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, chat, quickblox

I have been trying to execute the following sample template provided by Quickblox in their master sdk for android.

https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-messages

I have created my own application id and I am successfully able to create users,chat in runtime but gcm doesn't seem to work at all.

I generated a successful api key and project number.The project above just seems to generate an empty GCM once and replaced it in the consts.java file.

I have tried a multiple things but to no avail.

The following piece of code executes correctly.

```
    QBMessages.createEvent(qbEvent, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBEvent qbEvent, Bundle bundle) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            // hide keyboard
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
                    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(messageOutEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List<String> strings) {
            // errors
            DialogUtils.showLong(MessagesActivity.this, strings.toString());

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            // hide keyboard
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
                    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(messageOutEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    });
```

but I dont recieve any notification.Upto my knowledge all settings in the admin panel are correct.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards
Karan

Comment: Push notifications  from console work

Comment: You need to logout from quickblox when you are in background to receive push. For more info visit: http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-android

Comment: logout from QB worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add GCM Api key in the QB admin panel of your application in Settings tab to check if there are subscribed devices; you can also have a look at Subscriptions tab there.
To check if everything is setup correctly, you can send push notifications from your QB admin panel to a definite platform (Android, iOS) - admin panel - >Your application - > Messages - > Send

To get more information you can also have a look at our Documentation:
http://quickblox.com/developers/Messages

Comment: Tried that.Console messages are working correctly.The chat app is not sending notification to offline users.

Comment: Karan, could you please specify in what cases push notifications to offline users fail in more detail?

Comment: you should logout from XMPP when you want to receive push notification i mean in background.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I'se added the GCM Server API Key in the admin panel, I've changed the project id, added the permissions to the manifest file, and the main reason why I had trouble with push notifications is because you need the user to be logged in before you init `PlayServicesHelper` class.

Hope this will help someone